# Finding Shortest Path

Tags: haskell, pathfinding

[Working on Functionally Solving Problems](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functionally-solving-problems#heathrow-to-london) from *Learn You a Haskell*, I worked on the "Heahtrow to London" shortest path problem.

I'm working on a reduced set of this problem in order to solve a simple problem first.

It's a shortest path problem for the following map:

[image]

The rule is: you start a `A` or `B`, and then choose across the bridge or up/down. When you reach `E` or `F` (doesn't matter), you're done.

I used a `Node` data structure (compliments of LYAH's previous chapter) to recurse through the shorter `left` or `right` sides. Ultimately, I return a tuple of `(collective cost, list of nodes traversed)`.

Please critique my implementation:

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

shortestPath2 :: Tree (Int, Char) -> (Int, [Char])
shortestPath2 EmptyTree = (0, [])
shortestPath2 (Node (c, pt) EmptyTree EmptyTree) = (c + fst (shortestPath2 EmptyTree), pt : snd (shortestPath2 EmptyTree))
shortestPath2 (Node (c, pt) EmptyTree right)     = (c + fst (shortestPath2 right), pt : snd (shortestPath2 right))
shortestPath2 (Node (c, pt) left EmptyTree)      = (c + fst (shortestPath2 left), pt : snd (shortestPath2 left))
shortestPath2 (Node (c, pt) left@(Node (lcost, _) _ _) right@(Node (rcost, _) _ _)) = 
                                 (c + fst (shortestPath2 next), pt : snd (shortestPath2 next))
                                       where next = if lcost < rcost then left else right


test3 :: (Int, String)
test3 = result 
        where path1 = (Node (50, 'A') (Node (30, 'C') (Node (90, 'D') (Node (0, 'E') EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree) EmptyTree)
                                     (Node (5, 'C') (Node (0, 'E') EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree)) 

              path2 = (Node (10, 'B') (Node (30, 'D') (Node (5, 'C') (Node (0, 'E') EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree) EmptyTree)
                                      (Node (90, 'D') (Node (0, 'F') EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree))

              sp1 = shortestPath2 path1
              sp2 = shortestPath2 path2
              compare first@(cost1, _) second@(cost2, _) = if cost1 < cost2 then first else second
              result = compare sp1 sp2
```

**Output**

> ```
> ghci> test3
> (45,"BDCE")
> ```

Answer (score 3):

### Data representation

My critique starts here:

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Why is a node forced to have 2 sub-trees? Given a graph like this:

```
    B1 - C1
     |    |
A - B2 - C2
     |    |
    B3 - C3
```

you cannot represent B2 properly. I'd use

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a [Tree a]
```

for an arbitrary number of subtrees. Even the `EmptyTree` constructor might turn out to be unnecessary.

Try to rewrite your code with that, and see that the code duplication in the `shortestPath2` definitions is reduced.

### Use let and pattern matching

In an expression like

```
(c + fst (shortestPath2 right), pt : snd (shortestPath2 right))
```

you calculate `shortestPath2 right` twice and calls to `fst` and `snd` can often be avoided with pattern matching.

```
let (cs,pts) = shortestPath2 right in (c + cs, pt : pts)
```

### Layout

```
path1 = (Node (50, 'A') (Node (30, 'C') (Node (90, 'D') (Node (0, 'E') EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree) EmptyTree)
                                       (Node (5, 'C') (Node (0, 'E') EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree))
```

is very hard to scan this by the eye. Only whitespace change, and it looks like this:

```
    where path1 = (Node (50, 'A') 
                      (Node (30, 'C')
                          (Node (90, 'D')
                              (Node ( 0, 'E') EmptyTree EmptyTree)
                               EmptyTree)
                           EmptyTree)
                      (Node (5, 'C') -- should be 'D'
                              (Node (0, 'E') EmptyTree EmptyTree) 
                               EmptyTree))
```

You actually have `'C'` twice as successor to `'A'`.
<strike>Change `path1` to a top-level definition to access it in ghci. Then type `let (Node _ a b) = path1` and then `a` and `b` into ghci. The latter should be `'D'`, just a typo.</strike>
The data representation is confusing me! The data is a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29), and graphs distinguish between *edges* and *nodes*. `A`,... are nodes, the numbers in between are edges. I would not group them like `(50, 'A')`. I hope someone else can give you a good pointer here.

BTW `path1` is a misnomer. It is not a path. `"BDCE"` might be a path. `path1` is a graph rolled out to a tree (without loops)?

### Algorithmic

> I used a Node data structure (compliments of LYAH's previous chapter) to recurse through the shorter left or right sides.

You are technically right. It only scans then next section of the path and uses the shorter one. Your algorithm is [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) and does not find the global optimum. Change the 90 into 31, the shortest path should be "BDF", but your output of `test3` does not change.

### In General

At first I was confused, because I'd expect a function like

```
`shortestPath from to path1`
```

where `from` and `to` are origin and destination nodes. In your code, the destination is not coded at all. The problem states get from A or B to E or F, but single nodes are enough:

You can insert a virtual node

```
`london = Node ('V',0) path1 path2`
```

and you test function looks like

```
test4 = shortestPath2 london where
        --path1 = -- see above
        --path2 = -- see above
        london = Node (0,'V') path1 path2
```

Which looks better than `test3`.

### Conclusion

I will address the biggest problem - that you algorithm does not find the optimum - in a later edit (or leave it for someone else to answer).